# DC-DC converter maximum current rating

Tags: current, dc-dc-converter, maximum-ratings

I am using an XP Power [XP-IL1224S](http://octopart.com/il1224s-xp+power-7519326) 12V to 24V DC-DC converter, does anyone have experience with the current rating of these kinds of parts?

The maximum current is rated as 84mA @ 24V, which works out to 2W - so this is an average current rating. 
How would I go about finding out the peak current rating? My application is drawing over 400mA for peak (for 40-80mS) and I am concerned about the longevity of part.

I've tried contacting the manufacturer but I've gotten no response back :(

Comment: Which part of "maximum" do you find confusing? If you need to draw short-term bursts higher than that, you'll need a suitable energy reservoir (capacitor).

Comment: It was more of a concern about the peak output current rating, which wasn't stated in the datasheet. And as you and Andy below have suggested, a capacitor to dampen the bursts is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to add up to 470uF on the converter's output and this will alleviate the situation in that it spreads the pulse of current you are taking over a longer time period with a smaller peak seen by the converter.

The problem is that the manufacturer states that 470uF is the max you can add and I suspect that if you added more it might prevent the converter working correctly. So this is to be avoided because, it probably needs to see a controlled amount of ripple on it's output to function properly.

A way to get round this is to use an inductor in series with the output then a decent sized capacitor to ground probably in the region of 1000uF. The inductor value depends on how long your surge lasts. The inductor "buffers" the motor output current peaks from the converter allowing it to still produce the ripple it needs to operate correctly.

The converter specifies that it's output ripple is 150mVp-p and the inductor is there to allow this to largely remain at that level. If I was at my work desk I'd simulate the effects but I'm not

Comment: Thanks! This is probably the better way to go, I'll see if the cap alone will be enough - it should since the load is an LED projector.